# Parameter mismatch using CustomAttributeBuilder (boxing decimal?)

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, reflection.emit

I have the following code as part of a system for generating interfaces using reflection.emit

```cs
void IPropertyCreator.AddAttribute<T>(params object[] args)
{
    // Convert args to types
    var argTypes = new Type[args.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; ++i)
    {
        argTypes[i] = args[i] != null ? args[i].GetType() : null;
    }
    // Get constructor
    var ctorInfo = typeof(T).GetConstructor(argTypes);

    // Create custom attribute
    var attrBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(ctorInfo, args);
    _propertyBuilder.SetCustomAttribute(attrBuilder);
}
```

In the case with an issue, I am creating an attribute (The `T` typeparam) with a constructor taking a single 
`object` parameter and the argument is a `decimal`
The attribute has (only) the following constructor

```cs
public DefaultValueAttribute(object value)
```

This code works fine with all POD types (`byte`, `char`, `int`, etc) and also `string` but fails when using `decimal`.  The constructor of `CustomAttributeBuilder` fails with exception **"Passed in argument value at index 0 does not match the parameter type"**.

Debugging shows that all the variables are as expected:
`args` has one element of type `object{decimal}`
`argTypes` has one element Type = `System.Decimal`
`ctorInfo` has correctly selected the (only) constructor which takes an object parameter.

I have demonstrated that the attribute can be instantiated by passing a decimal parameter directly:

```cs
decimal val = 123.456M;
var attr = new DefaultValueAttribute(val);
```

I have tried converting the decimal to an `object` and a `System.Decimal` to no effect.
I suspect the issue is related to the fact that `decimal` is not a POD type as such but a structure.

I tried adding a constructor overload to the attribute (taking `decimal` type).  The above function picked up the new constructor correctly but then failed in the same place with the exception **"An invalid type was used as a custom attribute constructor argument, field or property"**

Does anyone have any ideas how I can work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try to write this in plain C# code:

```
class TestAttribute : Attribute {
    public TestAttribute(object value) { }
}

[Test(1.2m)]         // NOTE: CS0182
class Example { }
```

You simply can't use System.Decimal for attribute constructor arguments.  Double is okay.  Section 17.1.3 of the C# language specification *hints* at the problem but isn't too specific about this particular case.  System.Decimal is a bit of a step-child of the standard value types.  It is never mentioned in the Ecma 335 for example.  The C# compiler makes it look like a basic type but the CLR doesn't treat it the same way.